# Encountering an Error when Integrating Scandit Android 4.0.1 with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, scandit

I attempted to incorporate Scandit Android 4.0.1, but I encountered the following error when initiating the Android call function. Has anyone else experienced this issue, or is it unique to me?

```
    06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin.ScanditSDKActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin.ScanditSDKActivity.initializeAndStartBarcodeRecognition(ScanditSDKActivity.java:218)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin.ScanditSDKActivity.onCreate(ScanditSDKActivity.java:50)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
06-30 21:58:34.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13096):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you set an odd value for "cameraSwitchVisibility", something like a bool or integer instead of a string. As you can see in the docs (http://docs.scandit.com/interface_cordova_plugin.html) the only allowed values are "never", "tablet" and "always".

Should this not resolve the issue please paste the cordova.exec call that you use in your app.